# C++ negation and overload resolution

Tags: c++, integer-promotion

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, the following code:

```
void foo(int8_t a);
void foo(int16_t a);
void foo(int16_t a, int16_t b);

void f()
{
    int8_t x /* = some value */;
    foo(-int16_t(x)); // ERROR
}
```

Gives the following message:

```
foo

Error: more than one instance of overloaded function "function" matches the argument list:
    function "foo(int8_t a)"
    function "foo(int16_t a)"
    argument types are: (int)
```

What is going on here? Shouldn't it say "argument types are: (int16_t)"? Does this have something to with promotion? if so how can I turn promotion off?

Comment: Negating the integer converts it to an `int`. What kind of conversion exactly do you want (both type conversion and negation)?

Comment: I wan't it to sign extend 'x' to a 16-bit integer, take the 2's complement of that, and then pass it to foo(int16_t a)

And I belive int is 32-bits on my computer, so why in the world is the negation of a 16-bit integer a 32-bit integer?

Comment: Negate before you cast. Negating promotes to a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Converting to `int` simply conforms to the C++ standard.

Comment: If you read about [integer promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion) you will see that it says that "In particular, [arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion," Negation is an arithmetic operator, and so the value is promoted to an `int`.

Comment: @Joseph thank you that answers my question! unfortunately you put that in a comment so Stack Overflow won't let me accept that as an answer :(

Also whose stupid idea was to make everything an int? it's totally confusion, not to mention potentially memory inefficient.

Comment: @Isaac I believe it's something to do with performance, in that machine size integers may be faster to operate on. Nowadays, intuitive behaviour is probably a much bigger concern, but we are stuck with legacy behaviour for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negate before you cast. Negating promotes to a machine size integer, hence the ambiguity.

```
foo(int16_t(-x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting about the *integer promotions*. All of the arithmetic operators perform integer promotions on the operands which are having arithmetic done to them.

In the expression `-a`, for any `a`,  the *integer promotions* are applied to `a`.  The effect of this is that if `a` is an integer type narrower than `int`, then the value is promoted to `int`.

On your system `int` is 32-bit, so `int16_t` is narrower, therefore `-(int16_t)x` means `-(int)(int16_t)x`.

If you want to do a negation in 16-bit precision: you can't; you have to do  it in `int` precision and then convert the result back to 16-bit.

In this case `foo( (int16_t)-x )` is the simplest way, although in general think about what you are negating.  Here `-x` is `-(int)x` but in this case that is presumably what you do want to do.  If we were using unsigned types you'd need to take more care.